# Saving Android App SQLLite Offline Data to Live Mysql Database

Tags: php, android, mysql, laravel, sqlite

I am a back-end developer providing API's for **an android application** which can operate on **online** and **offline** also.

**Application Overview:**

Users can make folders, Sub folders, Files, and Comments on files. Folders or Sub folders can also be shared to other users. Folders or Sub folders or Files can also be made favorites.

While with internet connection, it works fine.

**Problem is** with offline, when junk of **data(e.g; For Folders & Sub Folders in Separate API, For Files in Separate API)** is send to the server from application how should i save the data? In which format how should i get data for folders and their sub folders also for files?

- As there is Parent Child relationships for Folders.
- Files which can belong to Folder or Sub Folder or Shared Folder.

We can not rely on SQL Lite Data ID's as those were different from Live Server Data. I just stuck in this scenario and can't find a proper solution.

Here is the database schema.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjpKf.jpg)

Sorry for something if not clarified well. Would Really appreciate if any can help.